# How to search for records between two dates when date is in varchar without seperators in database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have dates stored in varchar column(bad idea i know) without date deperators.. in ddMMyyy format .. `Example: 23-10-2013 is stored as 23102013` in database. Now i want to search for records between two particular dates such as `12-10-2013 and 20-10-2013` How do I come about this?
I am using SQL Server

Comment: you can use `between` operator in your `TSQL`

Comment: But i have dates stored without seperators in varchar format .. i dont think between will work. `20092013` would be greater than `19202013` which would be wrong.

Comment: ...which is exactly why storing dates like this is problematic.  If you at least had it in `yyyyMMdd` format (regardless of separators) you wouldn't need to convert it (ie, queries would be likely to use indicies), but as it is you've now noticed that the db design is shooting you in the foot.  To say nothing of the fact that you've lost built-in bounds checking...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, 
       LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, t.[parseddate], 120), 10) AS ParsedDate2 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               CONVERT(DATETIME, Stuff(Stuff([startdate], 3, 0, '-'), 6, 0, '-') 
               , 105) 
                      AS 
               ParsedDate 
        FROM   mytable) AS t 
WHERE  t.[parseddate] BETWEEN '2013/10/10' AND '2013/10/20'
```

You may see it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/251f4/19).

For the available date and time styles, take a look at this MSDN article:

> [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: I must say your solution is short, simple and sweet, Its awesome! ThanX

Comment: You my friend are genius! Btw how can I display dates as `2013/10/10` or `2013-10-10` in the final result set?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici .. its still the same.. your solution is working fine! But if i could display the final result set with seperators inserted in dates then it would be great! Right now your solution displays dates as they are stored in database ie. without seperators.

Comment: Note that this will not be able to use any indicies on `startdate` (due to the conversions).  Also, the use of `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types ([especially on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)) should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you 3 solutions.
1-update your column add -  eg:23052012 --> 23-05-2012 you can use substring to reach goal and then I will work fine with comparison operators.
Note it is work for just dd-mm-yyyy
2-use substring to separate first 2 digits as day and others then compare integers with variables.
3- convert(date,yourdate)

Comment: The (lack of) separators isn't the issue, really; it's the use of a poorly-sorting format (if you're attempting to point that out in your answer, I'm afraid it's not completely clear).  And comparing the variables as integers probably doesn't help much either (because the comparison logic gets terribly complicated).  The only real solution is to convert the dates, hopefully permanently.

Comment: That is my third solution.

Comment: ... I noticed.  What I'm saying is that the other two aren't really worth anything.